# Cannot boot unto Ubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

Computer components:
Device name DESKTOP-LVM1PF2
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz   3.40 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display

Motherboard: HP 3397

When I first installed Ubuntu I could boot into it, after that I booted into Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit UEFI

I restarted my computer again and Grub wasn't appearing, I tried going to Boot Order, no grub or ubuntu,

I tried going into the boot menu but no grub or ubuntu

Whenever I install DEBIAN I have the same issue but I see it in the boot menu

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu or Debian?

Comment: Many with HP need UEFI updates & if SSD, SSD firmware update. And HP does not recognize efibootmgr change to boot order that grub uses on grub install. You  have to change boot order in HP's UEFI settings & boot tab.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GRUB will be destroyed once you boot into windows, so you have to disable secure boot before accessing windows 10.

If its destroyed, insert ubuntu installation media and select "Try Ubuntu". then execute:

```
sudo apt install boot-repair
```

Then open boot-repair and select recommended repair. Wait until the process finishes and reboot your pc and it should boot.

Comment: *GRUB will be destroyed once you boot into windows* Sources? That's not how it works in any modern UEFI system. Windows feature updates in BIOS/Legacy installations have rewritten the bootloader ideed but that doesn't happen with UEFI -and- it has nothing to do with Secure Boot. The suggestion about Boot Repair is fine but wrong in the method because Boot Repair is NOT installed by default in a live session.

Comment: i will try it :D

Comment: It worked! I am on ubuntu right now! will try restarting

Comment: i do have to do sudo apt-get install boot-repair everytime but it works!